# How do I redirect to a result page and scrape from there using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, redirect

I try to scrape some flight data from kayak.com, but if I put in the result page's URL, it keeps redirecting me to a bot captcha page.

I tried using scrapy-user-agent and scrapy-fake-useragent-fix somehow it still returing the same result

```py
import scrapy

class FlightSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name  = 'kayak'
    allowed_domains = 'www.kayak.com/'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.kayak.com.au/flights/PER-MEL/2019-05-01?sort=price_a'
    ]

    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def parse(self, response):
        #test to save the result page in HTML
        filename = 'test-1.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        #extract the departure time
        for flights_time in response.xpath("//div[@class='resultWrapper']"):
            yield {
                'dep_time' : flights_time.xpath(".//span[@class='depart-time base-time']").extract_first()
            }
```

And this is the error I get

```py
2019-04-16 18:28:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://www.kayak.com.au/flights/PER-MEL/2019-05-01?sort=price_a> (referer: https://www.kayak.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

> it keeps redirecting me to a bot captcha page.

Because they know you are a bot. You can do three things to prevent this:

1. In settings.py tweak the following variables. With this you can make your calls more random. This is the most simplest way to improve your scraper. However, I think it is not sufficient to bypass the kayak security.

Example Code:

```py
DOWNLOAD_DELAY=0.75                                                        
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY=True                             
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED=True
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY=4
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY=1.25
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG=False
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY=1.5        
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=1 #Default 4
```

---

2. User-Agent, you already mentioned it. In the settings.py you can set the `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`.

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
    'scraper1.middlewares.randomproxy.RandomProxyMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scraper1.middlewares.randomuseragent.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

Here you can add some custom middlewares for your purpose. Try to get a simple list of 100/200 user agents: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

---

3. The same counts for proxies. You will need different proxies to make your requests as random as possible.

Something like this in the middleware:

```py
class RandomProxyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        super(RandomProxyMiddleware, self).__init__()

        # Get proxies from DB
        try:
            proxy_list = ProxyService.get_proxies()
        except:
            logging.critical('Failed to get proxies')

        self.proxies = []

        for proxy in proxy_list:
            self.proxies.append('http://' + str(proxy[0]) + ':' + str(proxy[1]))
```

---

**Edited Example for Middleware proxies.**

```py
class RandomProxyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        super(RandomProxyMiddleware, self).__init__()

        self.proxies = [
            'proxy1.com:8000',
            'proxy2.com:8031'
        ]
```

You can also take a look at this library: https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-rotating-proxies/

Which would actually do the same with some extra stuff, like checking if the proxies are still valid.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your respond. I got the first 2 things you suggested and still got redirected to the captcha page. But I am not quite sure about the 3rd one. I mean where should I put these lines of code?

Comment: I was already afraid for that. The third part is an example of a customized middleware for dealing with proxies. In our cases we had a pool of paid proxies which we randomly used. First: try to get a pool of free/paid proxies. Test them so you know for sure they work. I will edit the answer for a more generic way of working. So you can just add your proxies.

Comment: I tried this proxy pool from GitHub, yet still no result. (https://github.com/hyan15/scrapy-proxy-pool)

Comment: You know for sure the requests are using different proxies?

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings in settings.py {scrapy only}:

```py
USER_AGENT  = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) ChromePlus/4.0.222.3 Chrome/4.0.222.3 Safari/532.2'
```

```
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'cookie': 'Apache=; kykprf=158; cluster=5; kayak=; p1.med.sid=; NSC_q5-tqbslmf=; xp-session-seg=; kayak.mc=; _pxhd=""; G_ENABLED_IDPS=; NSC_q5-lbqj=;',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'
}
```

later use throttle and proxy_rotation to keep it stable.